# How to Have a Fullscreen Background that Doesn't Zoom In

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly new to html and css so sorry if this is a stupid question. Right now I have a background image that I covers the entire page. Problem is that sometimes when I try to enlarge other images or videos the background 'zooms in' on itself for no reason.

```
  body {
    background-image: url("img/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
```

This is what I have right now in css. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow! =D
So, in a website im making i also have a fixxed image background and ive made the pic fit the background using the code below:

```css
  background-image: url('img/background.jpg');
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
```

I'm not sure if it'll work on your code but if im being honest, i think it'll be the solution you need.

btw quick tip, png files are large so it may cause your website to be slow on loading times, ive been there, so i'd recommend you use jpg files instead.

Comment: you may have to add `overflow-y: scroll` to ensure scrolling if needed. OT: using jpg over png is in general only better when you have a lot of different "colorpixels". this is more or less the case for photos. classic UX/UI elements often prefer png/svg.

Comment: this is part of a longer list of css items i used for making a fixed background parallax style, but thats the one he'd need. and thanks for the tip on the png/svg